# finding a number in space separated list with REGEXP

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am writing a SQL query to select row, where a field with space separated numbers contains a single number, in this example the 1.

Example fields:

- `"1 2 3 4 5 11 12 21"` - match, contains number one
- `"2 3 4 6 11 101"`    - no match, does not contain number one

The best query so far is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from " . $table . " WHERE brands REGEXP '[/^1$/]' ORDER BY name ASC;";
```

Problem is that this `REGEXP` also finds 11 a match

I read many suggestions on other post, for instance `[\d]{1}`, but the result always is the same. 
Is it possible to accomplish what I want, and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
WHERE brands REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]'
```

`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` match word boundaries before and after a word.

Comment: What is the difference between `[[:<:]]`/`[[:>:]]` and `\b`?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `\b` in its regular expression language. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: [MySQL regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html) uses [Henry Spencer's implementation of regular expressions](http://www.arglist.com/regex/regex7).

Comment: This confirms what I already thought and planned, I need to study REGEXP more closely. I did RTFM so to speak, but more for use of it in .htaccess.
I had no idea that there are differences between use in MySQL and other languages for instance.

Comment: There are some differences in regular expressions in almost every application that uses them, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regex: You can use `LIKE` if you add a space to the front and back of the column:

```
SELECT * from $table
WHERE CONCAT(' ', brands, ' ') LIKE '% 1 %'
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Shoudnt a wildcard or two be in there somewhere?

Comment: @mihai ah yeah. Oops! Fixed now.

Comment: In my case it is not so important because of the small scale. But generally speaking, which method is more efficient?

Comment: @lex the regex method is most efficient. This answer is more efficient than using find_in_set()

Answer (score 2):

Why not [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) + [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) ?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(1, REPLACE(`brands`, ' ', ','))
ORDER BY
    `name` ASC;
```